# How to auto-execute smart contract's function by Aion or other method in the private chain?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, contract-design, scheduling

I was a little bit confused about Aion scheduling system, because I want to do it on the private chain, in the example https://github.com/ETH-Pantheon/Aion, they have both smart contract Aion and MyContract, for this line of code [aion = Aion(0xFcFB45679539667f7ed55FA59A15c8Cad73d9a4E);], they have already deployed Aion in MainNet or Ropsten network. In my case, how do I deploy Aion in my private chain, then I can get the address to complete this line of code[aion = Aion(address);], or if my concept is incorrect please correct me thanks.
Or there are better solution to auto-execute smart contract's function in the private chain please tell me, because I know it can use node schedule to do it, but I didn't find any example about that, if there are any example, please tell me thanks.

Comment: You can deploy the Aion contract in the same way that you deploy any other contract. Then, you get the deployed address and use it in your contract as in the link that you provided. However you need to build the `executor`, that will check the requests and send the transactions. Deploying the two contracts is not enough.

Comment: Is that the content of Aion smart contract? or this is not Aion smart contract:                                                contract Aion {
    uint256 public serviceFee;
    function ScheduleCall(uint256 blocknumber, address to, uint256 value, uint256 gaslimit, uint256 gasprice, bytes data, bool schedType) public payable returns (uint);
}

Comment: No, in the repository that you mention there is a folder called contacts, there you can find the Aion contract. What you mention is an interface to the contract.

Comment: Are there any pages or website to teach how to build the executor? thanks

Comment: Check the Github page of Aion, there is now a code (executor) that allows you to launch Aion in your private network